# Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, inheritance

I'm coding a JavaScript client to a REST JSON API. Since I don't want it to depend on any other libraries I'm doing it with vanilla javascript.

Everything have been working great, but I'm having troubles with the inheritance in IE (it works in every other browser). I'm doing it like this;

```
/**
* BaseClass
*/
api.BaseClass = function(something) {
  this.someFunction(something);
};

api.BaseClass.prototype.someFunction = function() {
   // Code...
};

/**
* Subclass
*/
api.SubClass = function(something) {
  // to make the constructor be called in the base
  this.base = api.BaseClass;
  this.base(something);
  delete this.base;
};

api.SubClass.prototype.__proto__ = api.BaseClass.prototype;

// here be subclass prototypes...
```

The error occurs when instantiating with `new api.SubClass('argument');` The instance didn't get the function "someFunction". Could someone guide me on how to correctly do inheritance that works even in IE.

Comment: check this article about inheritence https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Comment: I've just published a JavaScript library called "jOOPL" that lets developers leverage object-oriented programming in JavaScript. Maybe you can give a try to it. It's open source: http://joopl.codeplex.com

Comment: Sorry for the possible "duplicate question". Those great "Related Posts" always appear just after you published the question (or I notice them then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because IE doesn't support `__proto__`.
you should do this instead:

```
api.SubClass.prototype = new api.BaseClass();
```

Comment: Then I can't pass arguments from the subclass:es constructor to the base class constructor?

Comment: @ullmark you can do that by api.SubClass.prototype = new api.BaseClass(something);

Comment: Although I didn't solve it exactly like this, it was pretty darn close! Thanks :)

Comment: Yes of course you can pass arguments to subclasses. All you have to do is, on SubClass constructor:
`api.SubClass = function(something) {
    BaseClass.call(this, something);

    ...
}`
Based on the answer given, don't forget to pass the constructor back to SubClass, so it's like this:
`api.SubClass.prototype = new api.BaseClass();
api.SubClass.prototype.constructor = api.SubClass;`

Comment: That does not work, because the new BaseClass object may have side effects: e.g. if the constructor check for parameters and throw an error, or there is class properties changes. Also, it is required to set the "constructor" property

Answer (score 3):

If you have done Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript, you will know that you can create a class as follows:

```
Person = function(id, name, age){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    alert('A new person has been accepted');
}
```

So far our class person only has two properties and we are going to give it some methods. A clean way of doing this is
to use its 'prototype' object.
Starting from JavaScript 1.1, the prototype object was introduced in JavaScript. This is a built in object that
simplifies the process of adding custom properties and methods to all instances of an object.
Let's add 2 methods to our class using its 'prototype' object as follows:

```
Person.prototype = {
    /** wake person up */
    wake_up: function() {
        alert('I am awake');
    },

    /** retrieve person's age */
    get_age: function() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Now we have defined our class Person. What if we wanted to define another class called Manager which inherits some properties from Person. There is no point redefining all this properties again when we define our Manager class, we can just set it to inherit from the class Person.
JavaScript doesn't have built in inheritance but we can use a technique to implement inheritance as follows:

`Inheritance_Manager = {};`//We create an inheritance manager class (the name is arbitrary)

Now let's give our inheritance class a method called extend which takes the baseClass and subClassas arguments.
Within the extend method, we will create an inner class called inheritance function inheritance() { }. The reason why we are using this inner
class is to avoid confusion between the baseClass and subClass prototypes.
Next we make the prototype of our inheritance class point to the baseClass prototype as with the following code:
inheritance.prototype = baseClass. prototype;
Then we copy the inheritance prototype into the subClass prototype as follows: subClass.prototype = new inheritance();
The next thing is to specify the constructor for our subClass as follows: subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
Once finished with our subClass prototyping, we can specify the next two lines of code to set some base class pointers.

```
subClass.baseConstructor = baseClass;
subClass.superClass = baseClass.prototype;
```

Here is the full code for our extend function:

```
Inheritance_Manager.extend = function(subClass, baseClass) {
    function inheritance() { }
    inheritance.prototype = baseClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype = new inheritance();
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
    subClass.baseConstructor = baseClass;
    subClass.superClass = baseClass.prototype;
}
```

Now that we have implemented our inheritance, we can start using it to extend our classes. In this case we are going to
extend our Person class into a Manager class as follows:

We define the Manager class

```
Manager = function(id, name, age, salary) {
    Person.baseConstructor.call(this, id, name, age);
    this.salary = salary;
    alert('A manager has been registered.');
}
```

we make it inherit form Person

```
Inheritance_Manager.extend(Manager, Person);
```

If you noticed, we have just called the extend method of our Inheritance_Manager class and passed the subClass Manager in our case and then the baseClass Person. Note that the order is very important here. If you swap them, the inheritance
will not work as you intended if at all.
Also note that you will need to specify this inheritance before you can actually define our subClass.
Now let us define our subClass:

We can add more methods as the one below. Our Manager class will always have the methods and properties defined in the Person class because it inherits from it.

```
Manager.prototype.lead = function(){
   alert('I am a good leader');
}
```

Now to test it let us create two objects, one from the class Person and one from the inherited class Manager:

```
var p = new Person(1, 'Joe Tester', 26);
var pm = new Manager(1, 'Joe Tester', 26, '20.000');
```

Feel free to get full code and more comments at: 
http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/how-to-implement-javascript-inheritance.aspx

Comment: +1 for listing the proper most compatible way for extending classes - for browsers that don't support Object.create()

Comment: Since you're putting ";" at the end of regular assignments, I think it's good practice to put it at the end of function and property assignments as well, as in "Variable.prototype = { .... };"

Comment: I think Joe Francis meant to call baseConstructor on the subclass, not the baseclass?